# Error 'Java Heap Space' in Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, error, attachment, bulk-api

With Data Loader (Version 44.0.0),I am trying to insert Attachments in Salesforce. There are 12k PDF files. Each file is around 190 kb. So total attachment are 2.28 GB

**This is the structure of my file**

[image]

After reading several posts I reduced batch size. 
In Data Loader, Setting I chose Batch Size 1 (Tried Batch Size 2000 first, then 30)

After successfully processing 1000 records, I got the 'Java Heap Space' error.

How could i successfully insert 12k attachments in Salesforce?

Can some one suggest blog or steps to do it in Jitterbit (free version) and Dataloader.io (free version)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the error comes from your machine running the bulk job. Try to increase your local java's heap Space limit.

Comment: ...in more concrete terms, [Data Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) launch scripts are available. You can write your own and/or modify a provided launch script to allocate more heap space.

Comment: I've used jitterbit before, but the upload resulted in multiple files being uploaded, but the contents were all the same. did a test with it first using the steps in the jitterbit documentation. so i decided to make my own for migrating files. never a need to use another tool.

Comment: As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329565&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1  'It might be required to go through several iterations of the steps above to find the right heap size'  which i am not in favor, too much time on unknown.  @identigral  can you give me an example of 'provided launch script' ? Will give jitterbit a shot.

Comment: It's a command rather than a packaged script, they're documented on github.